# Do we have a replacement for session.disconnect() on Hibernate 6?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-6.x

In hibernate 5, we have `session.disconnect()` where we could disconnect the session from its underlying JDBC connection, for example:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

----

try (Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)) {
    session.disconnect();
}
```

I could not find it on the [Session on Hibernate 6](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html). Anyone knows another way to disconnect from the current session?

PS: I was using `disconnect()` in Hibernate 5 when I had two data sources and I needed to switch between them.

Comment: Found [the commit](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/61772103958cc8aacad80064edaf1bde92a59acf) that was removed, the comment is the best: "this stuff is so old and so bad that it's not even worth deprecating"

Comment: Why not create a second session then to connect to the other datasource?